# ASP.NET directories blocked from VisualSVN Server behind reverse proxy in IIS 6

Tags: iis, asp.net, reverse-proxy, visualsvn-server

I’ve got VisualSVN Server running behind a reverse proxy in IIS 6, Windows Server 2003. This isn’t ideal, but for the main web app on the server I’ve only got one IP address and SSL certificate available.

Everything works except for when trying to commit to or browse the default ASP.NET directories (App_Browsers, App_Code, App_Data). SVN commits fail for these directories – which I believe is because IIS will never serve them by default.

The reverse proxy uses a virtual directory in IIS – is there a change I can make in the web.config for this virtual directory to get around the issue?

Comment: What errors do you get in a web browser and in a client? What errors do you see on the log?

Comment: Browser: "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: SVN Client: "Commit failed. Unable to connect to a repository URL. 'trunk/App_Code' path not found." Log: "Item 'trunk/App_Code' is out of date  [409, #170004]"

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer to this? I'm also having problems running VisualSVN behind a reverse proxy in IIS.